# How to extract columns from one file and move to another file without printing the columns?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, csv, columns

I have a 2GB csv file called data.csv. I want to extract 5 columns from data.csv and move to a new file (preferably a new csv file).

How can I do that? Is there an awk command which allows me to do that without actually printing the columns?

Comment: What do you mean by `without actually printing the columns`? You can't put values into a file without printing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
csv 1 3 4 6 7 <data.csv >new.csv
```

- assuming columns 1 3 4 6 and 7 of course!  For RHEL and clones the command `csv` is in EPEL and can be installed in the usual way.  For Ubuntu and its friends try:

```
csvtool col 1,3,4,6,7 data.csv >new.csv
```

For example:

```
$ cat data.csv
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p
a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l
z,x,c,v,b,n,m
$ csvtool col 1,2,3,4,5 data.csv >new.csv
$ cat new.csv 
1,2,3,4,5
q,w,e,r,t
a,s,d,f,g
z,x,c,v,b
```

instead.

Comment: Tried the csvtool command: ```csvtool col 1,2,3,4,5 <data.csv >new.csv``` but New.csv file is empty.

Comment: Apologies, csvtool requires a filename unlike csv which reads from stdin.  See corrected answer and example.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: @ilkayn you know that's printing the columns, right? It's still not clear what you mean in your question by `without actually printing the columns`.

Answer (score 1):

For that simple case without any `csv` specific extravagances, `cut` might do:

```
cut -d, -f1-5 file
1,2,3,4,5
q,w,e,r,t
a,s,d,f,g
z,x,c,v,b
```

or, for single non-contiguous fields,

```
cut -d, -f1,3,7 file
1,3,7
q,e,u
a,d,j
z,c,m
```

Redirect to the desired new `.csv` file.